# Netlify Page Not Found after update to code

Tags: http-status-code-404, create-react-app, netlify

I'm getting a page not found error on my netlify react site after updating my code. It was working before the update and I'm not sure why it doesn't work now. All I updated was some CSS. No new files, dependencies, etc. I did the usual git add, git commit, git push and netlify did an automatic deploy since I connected my github repo. Only now it doesn't work.

Some more context: I am using heroku to host the server for my site. Netlify for the front end. To deploy to netlify, I cd'd into my client folder, ran 'npm run build' and then dragged and dropped the build file into netlify. Netlify worked it's magic and the site was working up until I pushed the changes.

I did some research on it and have tried several things like:

changing the build command to CI = npm run build

adding environmental variables "CI" as the key and "false" as the value

adding environmental variables "NPM_FLAGS" as the key and "--legacy-peer-deps" as the value (this is what I currently have in my settings"

and these have not worked. If I trigger a deploy I get:

```
11:01:50 PM: Build ready to start
11:02:12 PM: build-image version: d7b3dbfb0846505993c9a131894d1858074c90b4 (focal)
11:02:12 PM: build-image tag: v4.10.1
11:02:12 PM: buildbot version: 67e75f1ba713a8213d4b5a8ccf9708af751e2390
11:02:12 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
11:02:12 PM: Starting to download cache of 139.9MB
11:02:13 PM: Finished downloading cache in 1.234733545s
11:02:13 PM: Starting to extract cache
11:02:15 PM: Finished extracting cache in 1.886946674s
11:02:15 PM: Finished fetching cache in 3.184475756s
11:02:15 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
11:02:15 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
11:02:15 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
11:02:16 PM: No build steps found, continuing to publishing
11:02:16 PM: Starting to deploy site from ''
11:02:16 PM: Creating deploy tree asynchronously
11:02:16 PM: Creating deploy upload records
11:02:18 PM: 1 new files to upload
11:02:18 PM: 0 new functions to upload
11:02:19 PM: Starting post processing
11:02:19 PM: Post processing - HTML
11:02:19 PM: Post processing - header rules
11:02:19 PM: Post processing - redirect rules
11:02:19 PM: Post processing done
11:02:20 PM: Uploading Cache of size 139.9MB
11:02:21 PM: Finished processing build request in 8.924801917s
11:02:22 PM: Site is live ✨
```

But the site still gives the Page Not Found error.

I think this might be because of my folder structure? My repo contains a client directory and a server directory. When I did the initial deploy I ran 'npm run build' in the client directory and deployed that. Maybe now that I pushed the code it is trying to build the whole repo and not just the client directory? If that might be the case, how I could I fix that issue?

Here is a link to the repo: https://github.com/vbrambila2/one-rep-max
Here is a link to the netlify site: https://onerep.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have pushed your `.eny` file to the repository.

The `.env` file should never be pushed to the GitHub repository.

Remove the file. And then revert back if your error is removed.